# In magento, how to add shipment and track number to order

Tags: magento, orders

I need to dynamically add a shipment and shipment track into an order, it needs to be dynamically because we will do it in batch, can you guys give me some help on this?

EDIT:
The user will see a page with a list of orders, then he will input the track number for each and submit the form, so I need to get a known carrier and send all orders via this carrier.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have a list of order ids and corresponding tracking numbers you can,

```
$shipment_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_shipment_collection');
$shipment_collection->addAttributeToFilter('order_id', $order_id);
```

Then you can go through all the shipments and add the tracking like,

```
foreach($shipment_collection as $sc) {
    $shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment');
    $shipment->load($sc->getId());
    if($shipment->getId() != '') { 
        $track = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_track')
                 ->setShipment($shipment)
                 ->setData('title', 'ShippingMethodName')
                 ->setData('number', $track_no)
                 ->setData('carrier_code', 'ShippingCarrierCode')
                 ->setData('order_id', $shipment->getData('order_id'))
                 ->save();
    }
}
```

You would need to have a nested loop of order ID and tracking ID on top of this code.

Comment: it didn't work, it never enters the shipment collection loop, would you know what would be the cause? thanks a lot!

Comment: ok try $shipment_collection->addAttributeToFilter('order_id', $order_id);

Answer (score 3):

here you go :)

```
    private function _createShipment($shipment, $itemsQty)
    {
        $itemsQtyArr = array();
        foreach ($itemsQty as $item)
        {
            $itemsQtyArr[$item->iExternalOrderId] = $item->dQtyShipped;
        }

        try
        {
            $shipmentIncrementId = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_api')->create($shipment->sOrderNumber, $itemsQtyArr, $shipment->sShipmentComment, true, true);

            if ($shipmentIncrementId)
            {
                Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_api')->addTrack($shipmentIncrementId, $shipment->sCarrierCode, $shipment->sTrackingTitle, $shipment->sTrackingNumber);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            Mage::log('Exception: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }

        return $shipmentIncrementId ? true : false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer, but how would I call that? I have an order at this moment, not the shipment or the quantity. Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: It's a function I wrote so just pop it somewhere ... or you could simply use parts of it. It uses the function in the Magento API to do what you requested. If you are going to ship all the stuff ordered. simple use the order items to get the quantities that are going to be shipped.

Comment: thanks elgabbu, the order items I understood, but I wouldn't know what to use as the $shipment argument. could you explain that please?

Comment: the shipment variable is simply an object that contains details about the shipment i.e. tracking numbers etc. you could simply pass an array with this information or else pass them as separate variables. Again you don't need to use the function exactly as it is ... just take the parts that are relevant to you.