# Invalid method Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment::create

Tags: php, magento

what does this means?

im trying to create a shipment for order programmatically, its throwing an error as i copied below.

my code:

```
if (!$order->canShip()) {
           echo 'can not ship this order';
           return false;
        }

$itemQty =  $order->getItemsCollection()->count();
$shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)
                        ->prepareShipment($itemQty);

 $shipmentId = $shipment->create($order->getIncrementId(), $itemQty, 'Shipment created through ShipMailInvoice', true, true);
```

Error is:

```
   <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'Varien_Exception' with message 'Invalid method     Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment::create(Array
(
[0] =&gt; $orderId
[1] =&gt; 8
[2] =&gt; Royal mail Shipment
[3] =&gt; 1
[4] =&gt; 1
)
)' 
in /home/toesocks/public_html/lib/Varien/Object.php:569
Stack trace:
#0 /home/toesocks/public_html/product_scanning/v2/functions/orderDispatch.php(82):     Varien_Object-&gt;__call('create', Array)
#1 /home/toesocks/public_html/product_scanning/v2/functions/orderDispatch.php(82):     Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment-&gt;create('15300007141', 8, 'Shipment create...', true, true)
#2 {main}
  thrown in <b>/home/toesocks/public_html/lib/Varien/Object.php</b> on line <b>569</b><br     />
```

Could someone please explain me what does this means and why am i getting this error?

Kind Regards

Jey

Comment: Hi Rob,

<Br>      if (!$order->canShip()) {
               echo 'can not ship this order';
      return false;
            }
   
    $itemQty =  $order->getItemsCollection()->count();
     $shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)
                            ->prepareShipment($itemQty);

    $shipmentId = $shipment->create($order->getIncrementId(),   $itemQty, 'Shipment created through ShipMailInvoice', true, true);

Comment: @Rob, you meant edit the question with that code? if so i have edited the question.

Comment: There are few precondition for a shipment ot be created. Are you sure that those preconditions have been achieved.

Comment: hi @SatishMantri, 

i have fixed the problem but for some reason i could not change the order status. i want order status to be set as completed after creating the shipment.

For some reason its not changing the status

**CODE** :

      $history = Mage::getModel('sales/order_status_history')
            ->setStatus('complete')
            ->setComment($comments);
        
  $order->addStatusHistory($history);
  
  $order->save();

Do you think you can help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting a PHP error, not necessarily and Magento one.  `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment` has no method `create()`.  You're asking for something that doesn't exist.

Take a look at `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment_Api::create()` to get an idea of how to create a new shipment.

See also: [In magento, how to add shipment and track number to order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6651725/763468)

You build the shipment with `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment::addItem()` and then "create" it with `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment::save()`.

Comment: i figured and shipment is creating now but for some reason changing the status is a problem. im able to change it manually via admin but i couldnt change it automatically. 

Still thanks for pointing it out though. really appriciate it